# Handling JSON objects with UUID keys while templating with Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I have a nested JSON object which looks like this

```
review:{
  body:{ 
    "1cfd0269-1b8f-418f-a7b2-45eb2fa7562b": "Text1",
    "38d14dcd-6e70-46f9-8d81-9c5237cb7393": "Text2",
    "01485828-39ef-4929-9e96-19758375eb9b": "Text3",
  }
  created_at: "2014-06-25T07:42:19Z",
  id: "ea07aaa3-9db6-4868-b6f1-0887ef77f8ba",
  product_id: "eb5a7c9c-c20d-4539-b04f-5a3fd8d26c87",
  updated_at: "2014-06-25T07:42:19Z"
  written_by: "09b3c6f1-cbcb-4544-8cc3-d073d17a8552",
  written_on: "2014-06-25"
}
```

The JS is pretty straight-forward:

```
var context = {review:review};
html = template(context);
```

The template is largish but relevant part is here

```
<textarea class="review-body"> {{body["1cfd0269-1b8f-418f-a7b2-45eb2fa7562b"]}} </textarea>
```

I am getting a Parse error while trying to access attributes of body in an html template. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 5:
...iew-edit-context">{{body["1cfd0269-1b8f-418f-a7b2-45eb2fa7562b"]}}</tex
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
```

Comment: What's the markup of your template like?

Comment: Its a largish template but the relevant part is here 

<textarea class="review-body">
 {{body[#1cfd0269-1b8f-418f-a7b2-45eb2fa7562b]}}
</textarea>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc on [Handlebars expressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) :

> To reference a property that is not a valid identifier, you can use segment-literal notation, [ :
>      {{#each articles.[10].[#comments]}}
>      {{/each}}

which means you have to use `{{body.[1cfd0269-1b8f-418f-a7b2-45eb2fa7562b]}}` in your template.

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/KVg9P/ for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

yes that is work on webpage and angularJS expression retrieve it fine  , but if you try to do the same in JavaScript it will return undefined error . for example if you try something like this

```
console.log(body.[1cfd0269-1b8f-418f-a7b2-45eb2fa7562b]);
```

or even

```
console.log(body['1cfd0269-1b8f-418f-a7b2-45eb2fa7562b']);
```

I do not the solution for it , but somewhere mention JavaScript is not like those mines sign on UUID , myself still looking for solution but temporary I am trying to remove the mine sign.